# TypeScript: How to convert type "n-tuple of getter functions" to type "n-tuple of returned values"?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Let's assume you have a function that has an array of getter functions as input and returns an array (of the same length) with the corresponding return values.

How does the type definition `type ValueTupleOf<...> = ...` has to look like in the following example?

```js
function getValues<A extends (() => any)[]>(getters: A): ValueTupleOf<A> {
  return getters.map(getter => getter())
}
```

---

Edit: Of course I could do something like the following but I hope there is a better solution:

```js
function getValues<A1>(getters: [() => A1]): [A1]
function getValues<A1, A2>(getters: [() => A1, () => A2]): [A1, A2]
function getValues<A1, A2, A3>(getters: [() => A1, () => A2, () => A3]): [A1, A2, A3]
// ... etc
function getValues(getters: any): any {
  return getters.map(getter => getter())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go... (Pretty self-explanatory) Also, [demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ReturnTypes%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R%20%3F%20R%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Getter%3CT%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0Afunction%20getValues%3CGetters%20extends%20Array%3CGetter%3E%3E(getters%3A%20Getters)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%3CReturnTypes%3CGetters%3E%3Egetters.map(getter%20%3D%3E%20getter())%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20values%20%3D%20getValues(%3C%5B()%20%3D%3E%20%22a1%22%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22a2%22%5D%3E%5B()%20%3D%3E%20%22a1%22%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22a2%22%5D)%0D%0A%2F*%20type%20of%20values%20is%20%5B%22a1%22%2C%20%22a2%22%5D%20(hover%20to%20check)%0D%0AIn%20latest%20TS%20version%20you%20can%20use%20%3Cconst%3E%20to%20make%20tuples%2C%0D%0Ainstead%20of%20writing%20things%20twice%20like%20I%20did%20here%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20foo%20%3D%20ReturnTypes%3C%5B()%20%3D%3E%20%22a1%22%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%22a2%22%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20foo%20is%20%5B%22a1%22%2C%20%22a2%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0AgetValues(%3C%5B(x%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%22a1%22%5D%3E%5B(x%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%22a1%22%5D)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Also%20type-safe%20%5E%20gives%20error%20)

```
type ReturnTypes<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never
}

type Getter<T = {}> = () => T;
function getValues<Getters extends Array<Getter>>(getters: Getters) {
  return <ReturnTypes<Getters>>getters.map(getter => getter())
}

let values = getValues(<[() => "a1", () => "a2"]>[() => "a1", () => "a2"])
/* type of values is ["a1", "a2"] (hover to check)
In latest TS version you can use <const> to make tuples,
instead of writing things twice like I did here
*/

type foo = ReturnTypes<[() => "a1", () => "a2"]>;
// foo is ["a1", "a2"]

getValues(<[(x: string) => "a1"]>[(x: string) => "a1"])
// Also type-safe ^ gives error
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Stick to overloads. They might look like a lot of work initially, but the alternative is even worse.

**Long answer**

TypeScript doesn't have variadic types, so in order to preserve the order of your tuple you'd have to use a trick. However, this trick is ugly and has limitations.

```
import { Reverse } from 'typepark';

type Thunk<T> = () => T;

type ReturnTypesOf<T extends Thunk<any>[], Length extends number = T['length'], Queue extends any[] = [], Index extends number = Queue['length']> = {
  done: Queue;
  next: ReturnTypesOf<T, Length, Prepend<ReturnType<T[Index]>, Queue>>;
}[Yield<Queue, Length>];

type Yield<Queue extends any[], Length extends number> =
  Queue['length'] extends Length
    ? 'done'
    : 'next';

type Prepend<T, U extends any[]> =
  ((head: T, ...tail: U) => void) extends ((...all: infer V) => void)
    ? V
    : [];

type T1 = ReturnTypesOf<[() => 1, () => 'foo']>; // ["foo", 1]
type T2 = Reverse<T1>; // [1, "foo"]
```

As you can see, it does the trick, but:

- Is super difficult to understand
- Yields results in reverse order
- When reversing the reverse order, one might fall into the *Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.* case.

**@jcalz's answer**

jcalz mentioned in the comment that mapped tuple types can be used. If you don't mind passing the arguments one after another (instead of passing an array), you could do that:

```
type AnyFunction = () => any;

/**
 * Mapped type, but for tuples.
 */
type ReturnTypesOf<T extends AnyFunction[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyFunction
    ? ReturnType<T[K]>
    : never
};

function getValues<T extends AnyFunction[]>(...functions: T) {
  return functions.map(callback => callback()) as ReturnTypesOf<T>;
}

const values = getValues(
  () => "foo",
  () => 42
)
```

Comment: FYI, TS3.1 introduced [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Comment: Thanks! That's correct. However, I couldn't get them to work when the argument is an array (as opposed to a parameter list) which the original API assumes.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, but you can persuade the compiler to infer arrays as tuples if you include a tuple type in the constraint, as in `function getValues<T extends AnyFunction[] | [AnyFunction]>(functions: T) { return functions.map(callback => callback()) as any as ReturnTypesOf<T>; }`.  It's some hoop-jumping but it does work as expected. 